# Flow interfaces versus object type aliases

Tags: interface, flowtype

What is the difference between these Flow type definitions?

```js
interface Vehicle {
  start(): void,
  stop(): void
}
```

```js
type Vehicle = {
  start(): void,
  stop(): void
};
```

As far as I can tell, they can be used in the same way.

Answer (score 14):

`interface`s and `type`s are similar, and the difference is mostly historical I believe. The recent changes to implement [property variance](https://flowtype.org/blog/2016/10/04/Property-Variance/) also brought the behavior of `type` more in line with the behavior of `interface`. I believe the goal is to eventually make them identical and possibly even remove `interface`.

There may still be subtle difference but for most uses I don't think you will notice a difference.

One major difference is that if you want to use `implements` (e.g. `class Foo implements Bar {...}`) then `Bar` must be an `interface` -- not a `type`. However it's worth noting that marking a class as implementing an interface is not mandatory. Flow implements structural subtyping so if you have a class instance you can pass it to something that expects a compatible `type` even without explicitly indicating that the class implements a particular interface.

Comment: Note there appears to have been some kind of regression in flow v0.89.0 where `type` suddenly isn't enforced the same way:

[https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDCAhgNZ4AquBAvGAN6phgDGZeAXGABQCUYNAHxgAzhgBOASwB2AcwDcqAL7oWcaWLBQ4cLiXJV8AhssWpgwMBQAWBNuTCSRYYmBiS8qbXAB09vHxmqDIYeOJQxCwE+ngAktKh4ZEEjMz+XHwCwmJScooq5pYAJACiAB74LBgl4uJw4qhqGhhgAEbE4nrs8YkRUcaMSmbt4n7sgahAA]

Changing to v0.88.0 works as expected.